# Import from file inside an archive (jar)

Tags: javascript, java

I have an application written in Java + JavaScript. Users can write plug-ins for this application using JavaScript by placing their files inside a `plugins` folder next to the Jar file. Some scripts might need access to internal JavaScript classes (e.g. the plugin should default export a class that extends the JavaScript `Plugin` class) but these classes are defined in JavaScript files that reside inside the Jar and are therefor inaccessible from outside the Jar since you can't `import Plugin from "../MyApp.jar/scripts/Plugin.js"`.

My only theoretical solution is to copy all script files from inside the Jar to a folder `scripts/` outside the Jar, but would that even work? Wouldn't the `Plugin` class from inside the Jar and outside the Jar be *different* `Plugin` classes? Or is JavaScript sufficiently dynamic that it doesn't matter as long as both `Plugin` classes are 100% identical?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a single global namespace. It does not matter if part of the code is loaded from your source archive and part from external files. You may be worried because in Java each *class loader* gets a namespace of its own, and things get confusing when a class is loaded by different class loader (the two copies look the same but are incompatible).

JavaScript does not have this problem.

Comment: Ah I see, so simply copying the files should work perfectly fine then? Thank god for dynamic scripting languages I guess haha.